# Creating a "Wizard" UI by dynamically listing questions and dynamic "input types"

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a situation where I have a database of questions that are tied to different objects in a list that I am selecting from a picker control. When that picker is selected, I need to make a call to the database to retrieve questions that are tied to that object through their ID's (already mapped in the DB). This is creating a dynamic "form" where the user will answer these questions based upon their selection and the number of questions will vary based on the database relationships. The questions table has a column that includes javascript input types and options where applicable (the same app is being built for web through Vue). I am able to dynamically load the questions and translate the input types (i.e. type:text = Entry, type:dropdown = Picker, etc.). I obviously have to iterate through each question object and build the UI in code-behind. My main question is, what is the best way to capture the data in these dynamically created inputs on form submission? This is more of a general question, but I can provide some sample code of what I have so far if desired.

Comment: "best" is always a matter of opinion.  As written your question is really too broad to be answered in SO's guidelines.

Comment: @Jason Apologies Jason for the question being so broad. I know it is somewhat of a generic question. I guess to further simplify the question I might ask is there a way for me to obtain data from every input on the page once submitted and is there a way to tie each input to its question?

Comment: Yes.  Build a data structure of some sort to do it.  I've done something similar with a Dictionary where the key was the GUID of the question, and the value was an object containing the user response